# React Scrollable and lockable side bars

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a scroll implementation similar to Facebook's feed in the way that they conditionally lock the side bars.  For example if the content in the side bars is shorter than the viewport then the side bars don't scroll.  If it does need to scroll, then it scrolls until the bottom of the side bar and stops at the end(all while allowing the center feed to keep scrolling)

The good part, I have almost all of this done, except for a few small issues and conditionally locking the side bars when they are fully in view.

The side bar contains quite a bit of data, and changes dynamically in height after everything is fetched.  So my plan is below:

```js
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const leftSideBar = this.leftSideBar.current;
    const scrollableWindow = window.innerHeight;
    const sideBarHeight = leftSideBar.scrollHeight;
    let offset = sideBarHeight - scrollableWindow;

    if (this.state.offset !== offset) {
      this.setState({ offset: offset });
      if (offset > 0) {
        this.setState({ lockScroll: false });
      } else {
        this.setState({ lockScroll: true });
      }
    }
  }
```

This seems to be working inconsistently, sometimes the `sideBarHeight` is incorrect and I think it is because the component is updated and I'm getting that value before it is rendered and the height changes?

Basically I'm wondering if there is a better approach to this?

Comment: If you look up `position: sticky` on caniuse.com, and you can live with the browser support, that is the best way to achieve that effect.

Comment: Right, so I should mention I'm using the `lockScroll` variable to dynamically update my CSS.  So if initially the components div is fully in the viewport I can use that and lock it there with `position: sticky` `top 100px` so it won't scroll.  The problem I'm facing is when it is not locked and the user scrolls to the end of the div into view how do I stop them from scrolling further?  I set the `position: sticky` but I think I need to set a `top`?  The top of the div is already hitting the top of the viewport.

Comment: I’d have to see your html to be able to answer accurately.